# jQuery large file upload very slow, ASP.NET Core

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc, large-files

I use jQuery unobtrusive ajax (`data-ajax="true"`) in an ASP.NET Core MVC site to upload a large file (multipart data) to the server.

I configured jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({               
      timeout: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // sets timeout to 3 seconds
      maxChunkSize: 500000 //  500KB
});
```

I use a 500KB buffer in the server to read and write the `Request.Body` stream (The same size).

But the upload for a 1 GB file is very slow and takes more than one hour, I tried to set chunks and buffer to 1 MB with almost the same result.

So how to make this fast without taking too much of the server memory?

Comment: Why do you think that 1MB size chunks will drain your server's memory? 1MB doesn't seem that big to me. In any case, the best way to answer your question is to run more tests and see if the upload time changes with bigger or smaller chunk sizes. I wouldn't expect to see big improvements though.

Comment: Pretty sure asp.net-MVC (if not done incorrectly) will *stream* the upload anyway, not something silly like transfer to an array then pass-by-value to the action.  Try removing the chunks and letting MVC do its thing.